# Gear Stick sticking but only when I’m driving in the city and doing a lot of gear changes

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, gear-stick, ka

I noticed when I’m doing city driving that my gear stick is getting stuck moving from 1st to 2nd gear. I brought the car to a mechanic and they replaced the clutch. Now a month later, I’m having the same issue.
I have a Ford ka plus any it’s 2017 model. It’s in great condition. On a day to day basis I’ve no issues on short trips (driving 20-30) mins but it’s when I have to travel into the city that it starts getting stuck.
I only bought the car in June.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please describe a little better as to what you mean by "my gear stick is getting stuck"? Is it not shifting at all, or does it shift out of 1st gear and not want to go into 2nd? It doesn't stick on any other gear changes (ie: 2nd to 3rd, etc)?

Comment: It doesn’t want to shift from 1st to 2nd gear. I have to really yank it down from one gear to the other. Same when I was moving from 2nd to 3rd gear.  Doesn’t happen going into 4th or 5th gear. 
Driving through the city there is a lot of stopping and starting and that’s when it happens. Ordinarily I’m nit driving in the city and so I don’t have to stop and start because of traffic, traffic lights etc.
I hope that makes it a bit clearer. I don’t quite know why it’s happening as a new clutch went in very recently.

Comment: It sounds as though the clutch isn't properly disengaging. Are you pressing the pedal all the way to the floor? Do you have trouble engaging first gear from standstill? How far do you have to lift it for the clutch to 'bite' when pulling away from standstill? Have you asked the clutch fitter? What did they say?

Comment: Yes, pressing it all the way to the floor. Not such an issue getting it into 1st gear from take off, but it is when I need to move up the gears. 
I will phone the garage tomorrow and talk to the mechanic who fitted the new clutch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trusting us with your transmission issue.

From the data provided, it sounds like your transmission's [synchronizers](https://tremec-blog.com/manual-transmission-synchronizers-101/) are beginning to fail. Basically, the synchroniers synch up the main shaft and the desired gear so that the teethe of the gears mesh up. I'm going to go on a limb and say that it growls at you when you attempt to engage each gear.

The reason why 2nd gear started going first is that, in city driving, you shift most often back and forth between 1st, 2nd, and 3rd and back again. So your 4th gear sits mainly unused. The reason why I reject your clutch as an issue is that it would happen in all gears, including reverse and 1st, which it isn't. The good news is that manual transmissions are much easier to work on, thus making them cheaper to work on.

Please let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I can’t say that they growl at all. But it’s definitely related as you say to the frequency of gear change in the city. 
The car is still under warranty so I’ll get it back to the garage in the new year. 
You think it’s damaging to continue driving when it gets like that?

Comment: If it's not grinding, then probably not. But I still wouldn't delay too long,  because I wouldn't be the farm on "probably"